# Correct usage of free()

Tags: c, pointers

I started to improve my basic C knowledge.

For that I tried to work with pointer data types.

I created a list like this:

```
typedef struct lsEle *listPointer;
typedef struct lsEle {int index; listPointer next; int value;} element;
```

with the global variable

```
listPointer header;
```

In my `remove(int index)` function I now want to remove the element from the list at the  index.

```
void removeAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index < 0) {
        printf("You have to enter a index >= 0\n");
        return;
    } else {
        listPointer tmp = header;
        if (index == 0) {
            if (header->next == NULL) {
                header = NULL;
            } else {
                header = header->next;
            }
            free(tmp);
        } else {
            int counter = 0;
            while (1) {
                if (tmp->index == index - 1) {
                    break;
                }
                if (tmp->next != NULL) {
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                    counter++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index - 1 != counter) {
                printf("You have to enter a index <= %d\n", counter);
                return;
            } else {
                listPointer tmp_tmp = tmp->next;
                tmp->next = tmp_tmp->next;
                free(tmp_tmp);
            }
        }
        //Now update all index
        while (1) {
            if (tmp->next != NULL) {
                tmp = tmp->next;
                tmp->index = tmp->index - 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine.

My question is now: Do I use free() correctly? My goal was to remove the element "object" from the heap.

What happens when I do not use free? After the function exit from `remove` I don't have access to `tmp_tmp` any more, but does the "removed" object stay in memory?

Comment: Assuming the code logic works, the answer to both of your questions is yes :)

Comment: I don't think you are using `free()` correctly, well actually depends on how you create elements. `free()` can only be used on pointers that have been returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`, as the manual states

Comment: You `free` a value (which is a pointer), not a variable. Read also about pointer aliasing. BTW, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: @Klaus All the "objects" were created like this `listPointer newElement = (listPointer) malloc(sizeof(element));`.

Comment: @Blobonat  Your code is invalid and has undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Can you pls give more details what you mean?

Comment: @Blobonat Ok so the `free()` should work as expected.

Comment: @Blobonat For example in general header can be equal to NULL but you are trying to access its fields like if (header->next == NULL) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I use free() correctly?

You use `free` correctly if you previously allocate memory with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

> What happens when I do not use free?

Memory is not deallocated and you got memory leak.

> After the function exit from remove I don't have access to tmp_tmp any more, but does the "removed" object stay in memory?

You deallocate memory pointed by `tmp_tmp` with `free(tmp_tmp)` so object removed from memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But when I don't use `free(tmp_tmp)` in my remove function where I have declared it, is there any way I can deallocate it later?

Comment: @Blobonat You can deallocate it later only if you have a pointer to the memory block you would like to deallocate. For `tmp_tmp` it's not true, as `tmp_tmp` value lost when execution left `else { }` block. This value also excluded from the list, so no one point to this memory block later. Finally you will get memory leak without `free(tmp_tmp)`.